# How to position separate parts of panorama in spherical coordinates in AutoPano?

Tags: panorama, image-stitching

Autopano was unable to stitch few parts of my panorama. So, I am to fix them manually, but failing.

My panorama consists of two pars, which were connected by AutoPano automatically, but it was unable to stitch two groups together.

I have entered an edit mode, but found no way to drag group of images. Furthermore, I found no any way to drag very single image.

If I select picture move mode

[image]

and drag single image

[image]

it moves remaining highly distorted:

[image]

How to move image so that hole disappear?